# Are concurrent Guzzle HTTP requests from a single php process performed on the same CPU core?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, guzzle

We're using a Guzzle client in our PHP application to fetch several thousand files from Amazon S3 using parallel requests (with a concurrency of 25)

We're running this on an Amazon EC2 instance. I've noticed that increasing the instance size produces negligable improvements in performance and on further inspection one of the CPU cores is saturated with no use of the others.

I would have expected that having 25 parallel request streams would mean 25 threads which could then be spread across cores, but it seems like they're all being handled by the same core.

Is there a reason why it works like this?

Comment: How long does it take? Where do you think the time is spend?

Comment: What SAPI? CGI, Apache module, CLI? E.g. in case of Apache, it depends on which MPM module is being used by the server. Also, how exactly are you creating the parallel requests?

Comment: @RolandStarke Time taken is depends on the number of items fetched but we're running over a large enough amount that it just bottlenecks on cpu

Comment: @marekful it's through cli. We're creating the requests using a guzzle CommandPool via the Amazon S3 SDK, with a concurrency of 25